Can't debug VS Code extension using CursorAI
When I debug a VS Code extension using CurosrAI, the commands defined in my package.json are not shown in the new Cursor Instance, and I get this in the DEBUG CONSOLE:
activating cursor retrieval extension isDev: false

I tried using vanilla VS Code to debug the exact same extension and it works just fine, but it doesn't seem to work on CurosrAI.

I have had the same issue.
Check out what vscode version cursor is using from the about menu
mine uses 1.93.1 while the hello world example auto-generated defaulted to 1.96.0
The solution was to downgrade the following in package.json and npm install again
...
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.93.0"
  },
...
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/vscode": "^1.93.0",
...


related:

https://forum.cursor.com/t/my-extension-is-not-being-activated-in-cursor/14463
https://forum.cursor.com/t/how-to-debug-a-vs-code-extension-using-cursorai/35717

